# How to write a trait with varying input types for each implementation

Tags: rust

I am looking to be able to compare a `Card` with another `Card` of the same type. For example an instance of a `HarryPotterCard` should be able to call its `.cmp()` method against another instance of a `HarryPotterCard`.

The issue that I am facing is if I put a `HarryPotterCard` in the implementation of the cmp function signature for `HarryPotterCard` it complains that the signatures dont match and if I put a regular `Card` type then I cannot access the `magic` and `cunning` attributes to compare against `self`

```
pub struct HarryPotterCard {
    name: String,
    magic: u32,
    cunning: u32,
}

pub struct DinosaurCard {
    name: String,
    height: f32,
    weight: f32,
}

pub trait Card {
    fn cmp(&self, other:Box<dyn Card>, field: &str) -> bool;
}

impl Card for DinosaurCard { {
    pub fn cmp(&self, other: Box<dyn DinosaurCard>, field: &str) -> bool {
        match field {
            "height" => self.height > other.height,
            "weight" => self.weight > other.weight,
        }

    }
}


impl Card for HarryPotterCard {
    pub fn cmp(&self, other: Box<dyn HarryPotterCard>, field: &str) -> bool {
        match field {
            "magic" => self.magic > other.magic,
            "cunning" => self.cunning > other.cunning,
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: side note: is there a reason you are using your own trait instead of the [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html)/[`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html) traits which is in the std library? a benefit of those is that it also provides operator overloads like `==`, `<`, and `>`

Comment: Rust will not implicitly implement a trait just because a type has the appropriate methods. You actually need to `impl Trait for Type { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want cards to be compared against another of the same type, you probably don't want to use `dyn`, since that would allow any type of cards to be compared, which is definitely not fair to the poor dinosaurs who have to fight a wizard. You can use `Self` in the trait declaration, which will limit the `other` to be the same type as `self`. To actually implement the trait though, you need to specify it explicitly in your `impl` block, otherwise it's just a normal method.

```rust
pub struct HarryPotterCard {
    name: String,
    magic: u32,
    cunning: u32,
}

pub struct DinosaurCard {
    name: String,
    height: f32,
    weight: f32,
}

pub trait Card {
    fn cmp(&self, other:Box<Self>, field: &str) -> bool;
}

impl Card for DinosaurCard {
    fn cmp(&self, other: Box<DinosaurCard>, field: &str) -> bool {
        match field {
            "height" => self.height > other.height,
            "weight" => self.weight > other.weight,
            _ => panic!("not a real field"),
        }
    }
}

impl Card for HarryPotterCard {
    fn cmp(&self, other: Box<HarryPotterCard>, field: &str) -> bool {
        match field {
            "magic" => self.magic > other.magic,
            "cunning" => self.cunning > other.cunning,
            _ => panic!("not a real field"),
        }
    }
}
```

Because you aren't able to use trait objects in this scenario (`dyn`), I would also suggest switching out `Box<WhateverCard>` with `&WhateverCard` so that it is a little friendlier to use, as you don't need to heap allocate your data when you call `cmp`.

Comment: Thanks this is just what I was looking for! The changes have broken something else but I will work through it haha

Comment: I also would agree that references would be better than `Box`. Note that `Box` can be dereferences into the contained object: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=54f86bf8246b42d71471f775afa7935b